# What's Neturei Karta's response to the current situation?

Tags: current-events, evil-resha, anti-semitism, zionism, israel

Everyone knows that Neturei Karta has befriended Iranian and Palestinian leaders. Is there any published material from them (articles, videos, etc) on the genocide that has just occurred? Whose side of the current situation are they on?

Comment: What is the current situation?

Comment: @DoubleAA How much detail do you need me to go into? Is that constructive feedback on not my being detailed enough about the butchery of Jews by Hamas? Or are you really completely ignorant of what is currently happening? Sorry, there's a time for being pointlessly pedantic and insensitive and this just isn't it. If you want to put more information on the question so readers can know in gory and horrifying detail exactly what I'm referring to, go right ahead and edit the question your own self. Because I'm just hurting too much to write any more.

Comment: Honest question, no snark or rhetoric intended- is this within scope of Mi Yodeya? It's not about Halacha (or does NK have Rabannim who make a Halachic argument for their position on the medina?); it’s about Israeli politics.

Comment: @Yehuda this question will still be around in 5 years and no one will know what you are talking about.

Comment: The point is not to use time-relative referents. Nobody should need to look at the date of a post and a history book to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a speach at a Palestine rally from a so called Neturei Karta activist. He says that he does not condone violence, but that it can only be expected in the face of Zionist crimes (which predate the 1948 establishment of a state). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8queaGlpm8A&pp=ygUNbmV0dXJlaSBrYXJ0YQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain if this question is within the parameters of Mi Yodeya, but there is Facebook page for NK USA and they have a post where one of their people is speaking at a pro-pali demonstration on Oct 10th or 11th.

Furthermore, this article from JTA indicates that they staged a counter-protest to a pro-Israel rally.

https://www.jta.org/2023/10/10/ny/your-fight-is-my-fight-thousands-rally-alongside-ny-leadership-to-grieve-and-back-israel-after-hamas-invasion

Comment: This is not a valid question for this site.

Comment: @sabbahillel Insofar as the Neturei Karta malshinim are Jews (albeit far outside the bounds of "amisecha"), how is their hashkafah on this not a valid question for the site?